# Git: Ahead and Behind together. How to solve?

Tags: git, project-management

I have a commit with `1 ahead` and `6 behind`.

What should I do in this situation?

I think, that solution might be like this:
`git push` 
and after
`git pull`

But I think, it can solve only `Behind`.
Maybe I am wrong.

```
-------*------*-----*-----*-----B
        \
         \
          \
           *-------A
```

I make my part and change sdk.
Now I want to merge with `B`.

Comment: Can you specify where the *branch* which is behind or ahead of what other branch is? It would also help if you would explain which one you "can solve" and why.

Comment: @honk I edited question, please, advise me what I should do

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`git pull` (or rather, the `git merge` part that `pull` does) will "solve" both 'ahead' and 'behind'.

**branch is X commits behind** means that there are X new (unmerged) commits on the branch which is being tracked by your current branch.

**branch is X commits ahead** analogously means that your branch has X new commits, which haven't been merged into the tracked branch yet.

Once you've pulled (thereby merging the remote changes into your local ones) and pushed (thereby publishing your changes and the merge to the remote), your own branch and the remote branch will point to the same commit, so neither is ahead or behind.

Comment: `git pull` did indeed resovle the "behind" problem, then I executed `git push` which cleared the "ahead".